# Rails Linking Files from Directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, file, upload

RUBY -v 1.8.7, Rails -v 2.3.8

I am trying to link files from public/data to the view and it's giving me a headache.  I know I should be able to do this on my own, but I lost my old rails book and ordered a new one from amazon and it should arrive within a week.... :*(

I did read up on the uploading files tutorial.

My issue:
I have about 3000 folders; each folder has about 3~5 files that go with it.

My Question:

- Should I create a db migration just to keep track of the addresses to the files?  so that it can be easily accessed? (ie. order.data_file.address; I am guessing "yes")
- Once the file is uploaded how do I link the file so the file is linked correctly for the view.

So anyways I got this down:

```
<% @files = Dir.glob("public/data/*") %>
<% for m in @files %>
<% new_file = m.to_s %>
<li><%= link_to m.to_s, new_file %> </li>
<% end %>
```

The link to the file ends up as: localhost:3000/public/data/temp.pdf

But this doesn't work and returns:

```
 No route matches "/public/data/temp.pdf" with {:method=>:get}
```

I am guessing I need something in the routes.rb to make it work....

```
 map.datafile '#{RAILRS_ROOT}/public/data/:id', :controller => 'upload'
```

Any help or advise is appreciated.

Comment: path = params[:post]
   send_file(path, :type => 'application/pdf', :disposition => 'inline')

Answer (score 0):

No special map.resources routes necessary.  No special controller method send_to.

Just get the link corrected by omitting the public part and it worked.  I used this following code from another issue.

```
    <% Dir["public/files/*.pdf"].each do |file| %>
    <li><%= link_to 'Letter', file[/\/.*/] %></li>
    <% end %>
```

Comment: Returns a new String with the given record separator removed from the end of str (if present). If $/ has not been changed from the default Ruby record separator, then chomp also removes carriage return characters (that is it will remove \n, \r, and \r\n).